# React Navigation Equivalent for Action.Main in React-Native-Router-Flux

Tags: redux, react-navigation

i m trying to implement a login with redux whereby once a user submits his email n password correctly, he will be navigated to another screen.

I tried this.props.navigation.navigate ('Screen2'), but it doesnt work

In react-native-router-flux, i used Actions.Main in actions to achieve this navigation. What is an equivalent in react-navigation to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `Actions` is `NavigationActions`

```
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation"

NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Screen2'})
```

Comment: Thanks Kingsley. I will try it out